# python locale strange error. what's going on here exactly?

Tags: python, macos, osx-snow-leopard, locale

So today I upgraded to bazaar 2.0.2, and I started receiving this message (I'm on snow leopard, btw):

```
bzr: warning: unknown locale: UTF-8
  Could not determine what text encoding to use.
  This error usually means your Python interpreter
  doesn't support the locale set by $LANG (en_US.UTF-8)
  Continuing with ascii encoding.
```

very strange, since my LANG is actually empty. Similar thing happen when I try to tinker with the locale module

```
Python 2.5.4 (r254:67916, Nov 30 2009, 14:09:22) 
[GCC 4.3.4] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import locale
>>> locale.getdefaultlocale()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/sbo/runtimes/lib/python2.5/locale.py", line 443, in getdefaultlocale
    return _parse_localename(localename)
  File "/Users/sbo/runtimes/lib/python2.5/locale.py", line 375, in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError, 'unknown locale: %s' % localename
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
```

exporting LANG does not help

```
sbo@dhcp-045:~ $ export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
sbo@dhcp-045:~ $ bzr
bzr: warning: unknown locale: UTF-8
  Could not determine what text encoding to use.
  This error usually means your Python interpreter
  doesn't support the locale set by $LANG (en_US.UTF-8)
  Continuing with ascii encoding.
```

However, this solved the problem

```
sbo@dhcp-045:~ $ export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
sbo@dhcp-045:~ $ export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

Python 2.5.4 (r254:67916, Nov 30 2009, 14:09:22) 
[GCC 4.3.4] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import locale
>>> locale.getdefaultlocale()
('en_US', 'UTF8')
```

Could you please explain what's going on here, for better googlability ?

Comment: Any further insights into your problem?

Comment: +1 the two "export" lines made my "ValueError: unknown locale:..." go away.

Comment: Thanks so much for those last two lines. Saved me and I'm sure a lot of other mac users plenty of time.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

2016 UPDATE: Turns out that [this is a Python bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue18378#msg215215) since at least 2013, very probably earlier too, consisting in Python not reacting well to non-GNU locales - like those found in Mac OS X and the BSDs. The bug is still open as of September 2016, and affects every Python version.

---

If there was no `LANG` environment variable set, chances are you had either an `LC_CTYPE` (the key variable) or `LC_ALL` (which overrides if set) environment variable set to `UTF-8`, which is not a valid OS X locale.  It's easy enough to reproduce with the Apple-supplied `/usr/bin/python` or with a custom python, as in your case, that was built with the 10.6 SDK (probably also the 10.5 SDK).  You won't be able to reproduce it that way with a python.org python; they are currently built with the 10.4 SDK where the locale APIs behave differently.

```
$ unset LANG
$ env | grep LC_
$ export LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
$ /usr/bin/python  # Apple-supplied python
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jul  7 2009, 23:51:51) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import locale ; locale.getdefaultlocale()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/locale.py", line 459, in getdefaultlocale
    return _parse_localename(localename)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/locale.py", line 391, in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError, 'unknown locale: %s' % localename
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
^D
$ /usr/local/bin/python2.6   # python.org python
Python 2.6.4 (r264:75821M, Oct 27 2009, 19:48:32) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import locale ; locale.getdefaultlocale()
(None, 'mac-roman')
>>>
```

EDIT:

There may be another piece to the puzzle.  A quick look at the `bzr` 2.0.1 I have installed indicates that the message you cite should only show up if `locale.getpreferredencoding()` raises a `locale.Error`.  One way that can happen is if the python `_locale.so` C extension can't be loaded and that can happen if there are permission problems on it.  For example, MacPorts currently is known to have [problems setting permissions if you have a customized umask](http://trac.macports.org/ticket/21389); I've been burned by that issue myself.  Check the permissions of `_locale.so` in the python `lib/python2.5/lib-dynload` directory and ensure it is `755`.  The full path for MacPorts should be:

```
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/lib-dynload/
```

Comment: The python I am using is installed by hand, it's not the standard python installation bundled with OSX. Also, it appears I have no _locale.so or _locale.dylib.... uh ?

Comment: There should be a _locale.so in lib-dynlib.  If not, your python was not built correctly on OS X and locale.py will fall back to some default behaviors.

Comment: @NedDeily, looks like you now know better than what this answer shows, since you gave a very good explanation in https://bugs.python.org/issue18378#msg215215. Maybe you could fix your answer? (For googlability, like the OP asked)

Comment: @hmijail, Thanks for jogging the memory.  I just took a quick look at it but I'm not sure that the OS X 10.6 Terminal app behaves the same way that the 10.9+ one does; certainly the System Preferences options are different. If anyone wants to take the time to investigate further, feel free to edit the answer; that's a feature of SO.

Answer (score 10):

I faced the same problem. When I ran `locale`, I noticed that the `LANG` and `LC_ALL` were unset. So I fixed this by adding the following lines in the `.bash_profile` file:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Then I simply ran:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

And this issue was fixed thereafter on my Mac.

Answer (score 4):

It's a Mac OS X problem. To see your locale settings, run `locale` in terminal. `locale -a` should list all locales that you have defined (that you may use as argument to LC_ALL).

Notice that `LC_ALL` and other `LC_*` variables take precedence over `LANG` when defined.

Comment: More specifically this is a problem with the environment not just with Mac OS X. Linux and other UNIX clones are prone to the same problems if you customize your environment and inadvertently leave things out.  Sometimes the problems appear immediately, and other times not until you really need them to work.  Yet another symptom of having too many ways to do the same thing...

Comment: @synack: This is something that has come up before with OS X, which is why *I don't* think it's because Stefano changed his environment.

Comment: @kaiser.se: Why do you think this is a problem and why with OS X?  Having an LC_CTYPE or LC_ALL set explains the behavior seen by the OP and is working as documented.  The example I gave fails exactly the same way on a current Debian Linux system with the exception that the newer bash on that system actually warns you when exporting LC_CTYPE to the invalid value "UTF-8".

Comment: Hey I realize you can make this fail on POSIX. However, what matters is that it seems to repeatedly come up on OS X, because of default configuration issues http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629699/locale-getlocale-problems-on-osx  http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.apple/16205

Comment: It certainly can be confusing and there is the issue of the python.org pythons using the 10.4 SDK/libs where locale was kind of broken (something I forgot about when writing my original response). Things are cleaner starting with 10.5. Also, python 3.1 has some cleanup in the locale area, e.g. you won't see mac-roman anymore. The OP, though, is clearly not using a python.org python.

Comment: This is not a Mac OS X problem, but a Python bug: it assumes locales behave the GNU way, which is not true in BSD environments like OS X: https://bugs.python.org/issue18378