# Adding a database to the Django Project using Sqlite3 with Python 2.7

Tags: python, database, django, python-2.7

I am trying to add a database to the Django Project using Sqlite3 and Python 2.7.

This is how my setting.py looks like:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'dev.db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

It allows me to create the database and it asks me to create the superuser:

```
You just installed Django's auth system, which means you don't have any superusers defined. Would you like to create one now? (yes/no):
```

When i type yes, it gives me this error msg.

Error msg:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/IMAC/work3/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/IMAC/work3/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/IMAC/work3/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Users/IMAC/work3/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/IMAC/work3/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/Users/IMAC/work3/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 110, in handle_noargs
    emit_post_sync_signal(created_models, verbosity, interactive, db)
  File "/Users/IMAC/work3/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 189, in emit_post_sync_signal
    interactive=interactive, db=db)
  File "/Users/IMAC/work3/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 172, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/Users/IMAC/work3/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 73, in create_superuser
    call_command("createsuperuser", interactive=True, database=db)
  File "/Users/IMAC/work3/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 150, in call_command
    return klass.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/Users/IMAC/work3/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/IMAC/work3/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 70, in handle
    default_username = get_default_username()
  File "/Users/IMAC/work3/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 105, in get_default_username
    default_username = get_system_username()
  File "/Users/IMAC/work3/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 85, in get_system_username
    return getpass.getuser().decode(locale.getdefaultlocale()[1])
  File "/Users/IMAC/work3/env/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 496, in getdefaultlocale
    return _parse_localename(localename)
  File "/Users/IMAC/work3/env/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 428, in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError, 'unknown locale: %s' % localename
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
```

How do i solve the error above? Why doesn't it allow me to add a superuser? what should i do? Could this problem because I am running Python 2.7?

Comment: So... is your question the "How do I add locales on OS X?"?

Comment: is it because i am running python 2.7?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Type this before you execute the python manage.py syncdb

```
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

This will solve the error.. Btw i was using mac os x python which was in /usr/bin/python.

Add it to the ./.bash_profile file so that it calls it automatically..

Answer (score 0):

I actually ran into this on windows recently. This is a hack, not a fix or an answer, but it might get you through your problem:

Put this at the top of your manage.py script

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('LANG','en_US')
```

http://keeyai.com/2012/02/17/django-deployment-create-superuser-fails-with-locale-error/