# django createsuperuser not working

Tags: python, django, eclipse

## .bash_profile

```
export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:usr/local/$
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"

export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

## .profile

```
export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:usr/local/my$
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

## error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 70, in handle
    default_username = get_default_username()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 105, in get_default_username
    default_username = get_system_username()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 85, in get_system_username
    return getpass.getuser().decode(locale.getdefaultlocale()[1])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/locale.py", line 459, in getdefaultlocale
    return _parse_localename(localename)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/locale.py", line 391, in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError, 'unknown locale: %s' % localename
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
```

## doubt

i changed my LANG to UTF-8 also  but still i am not able to solve the problem , please help

Comment: Did you fix the problem by following iblazevic's instruction?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are seeing this because you don't have locale set on your system. You need to set it in order to create superuser, it's known and reported "bug" already.

see:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17649

Assuming that you're using linux you can fix that bug with

```
export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

You use this in terminal, but you can easily check and see how to change locales on your system just googling.

If you're using:

Ubuntu - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale/

Archlinux - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Locale

...

Comment: +1. The 'master' bug is: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16017. Can be fixed using `export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"`

Comment: where am i supposed to use export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"

Answer (score 12):

The accepted answer didn't work for me, so I keep searching around and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10894385/359248). It works for me. For sake of time saving I copy paste the two lines here. Enter this in terminal:

```
$ LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
$ LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Note: I use Mac OS 10.7 if that's relevant. Setting locale in system preference didn't work for me either.

Comment: This solved my problem. You can find a detailed description with trace [here](http://www.alirazabhayani.com/2015/01/django-syncdb-create-superuser-error-unknown-locale-utf-8-solved.html)