# Why LC_CTYPE needs to be set manually for Python in some cases

Tags: python, django, unix, utf-8

I am trying to use Django's Admin documentation. I followed [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/admindocs/) tutorial and installed **docutils**. After installing I run Django development server through **python manage.py runserver** and get error **unknown locale: UTF-8**.

I solved issue as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593556/django-createsuperuser-not-working) question:

```
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

But my question is: **What is origin of this problem?** It seems **docutils** has some compatibility problem with **Python** or something else?

Comment: AFAIK it is a problem with your operating system (Ubuntu, OSX).

Comment: Many python apps have the same problem.  For example AWS CLI tool on OS X.  This rules out docutils.

Comment: Another option is to prevent Terminal to set locale automatically. iTerm -> Prefs -> Profile -> Terminal OR Terminal -> Prefs -> Settings ->Advanced

Answer (score 2):

This is old issue, but still happening on OSX El Capitan. The origin of this problem is that Python assumes locale environment variable to be in format of language_region.encoding. This assumption is strict on Python's part as OSX defaults to UTF-8 when valid language and region pair is not available.

Lengthy discussion about this issue at [bugs.python.org](https://bugs.python.org/issue18378)

Comment: Same issue on OSX 10.14.2, fixed it by changing my primary language to `English (US)` instead of `English`.