# PyCharm is changing the default encoding in my Django app

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I am running into an issue where `plyplus` is erroring out with:

```
  File "/Users/FOO/.virtualenvs/ff/lib/python2.7/site-packages/plyplus/grammars/__init__.py", line 6, in open
    return _open( os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), grammar_name) )
LookupError: unknown encoding: 
[06/Jan/2017 22:27:45] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 500 200257
```

If I add `import locale; print 'LOCALE: [' + locale.getpreferredencoding() + ']'` to my `settings.py` and run the Django server from PyCharm (2016.3.1) I see `LOCALE: []` this when I start my server.

If I run the server from the command line, I see `LOCALE: [UTF-8]` and the `plyplus` issue goes away.

Can anyone tell me what I need to do in PyCharm to get the proper encoding set in my Django server?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting the encoding of `settings.py`? Of course, this would only be a temporary solution but a fix nonetheless.

Comment: I tried setting the encoding to UTF-8 and it did not take.

Answer (score 11):

PyCharm passes a blank value for the `LC_CTYPE` environment variable.

I need to explicitly add an environment variable to my run config: `LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8`

My shell has this environment variable set. It's strange that PyCharm sets it to a blank value.

Answer (score 0):

Coming from OSX 10.14.2, I fixed it by changing my primary language to `English (US)` instead of `English`.

This is also discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38557558/4960855