# encoding error in pycharm for python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, pycharm

I'm using python3 in pycharm but it seems that pycharm doesn't take utf8 as default encoding method.

For example, I try to open with out setting encoding parameter and print a line

```
with open('/Users/test.txt','r') as file:
    print(file.readline())
```

and then I got

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

While I can open the file without setting the 'encoding' parameter in iterm2 and Jupyter notebook. So I guess it is due to the encoding setting in pycharm, and I have tried every encoding setting in pycharm it also didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested on python-IDLE while not on pycharm, and I got the same response as yours. The encoding of file is UTF-8, while the encoding method used open the file is ASCII. I've found 2 solutions to avoid this:

#### Change the encoding method used to open the file:

The `codec` module contains some operation to do this. For convenience, you can directly pass a encoding parameter in your code to declare the encoding method.

```
with open('/Users/test.txt','r',encoding="utf-8") as file:
    print(file.readline())
```

#### Change the encoding method of the file:

There are many ways to change the encoding method of a file. If you are using Windows OS, that will be more convenient.
Open the `test.txt` file using Notepad, then click **File** > **Save as...**. In the **Save as** interface, change the encoding of file(at the bottom position) from **UTF-8** to **ANSI**, finally **Save** and **replace** the original file. After doing this, try to run the code in either pycharm or other IDE, and you will get correct result. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for answering this question, I can **open** with setting the **encoding=utf-8** parameter explicitly, but I just confused about why the default setting is not 'utf-8' in pycharm. what's more when I try to write the logging information into file, it also raises the same error and I have to manually set the encoding method with **logging.FileHandler**.

Comment: Anyway, this problem may be trivial and there may be not many people meet the same question, it just needs me to set the **encoding** parameter explicitly every time.

Comment: Hmmm, the default file encoding in pycharm is UTF-8 on my computer. Maybe you can reset it to UTF-8 and try that code again?

Answer (score 3):

PyCharm passes a blank value for the `LC_CTYPE` environment variable:

Please see: [PyCharm is changing the default encoding in my Django app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41514683/pycharm-is-changing-the-default-encoding-in-my-django-app/41514919#41514919)