# Having an issue upgrading dotcloud cli

Tags: dotcloud

Following the instructions here: http://docs.dotcloud.com/0.9/guides/migration/

When I ran `sudo pip install -U dotcloud`

```
Downloading/unpacking dotcloud
  Downloading dotcloud-0.9.2.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package dotcloud
Downloading/unpacking argparse (from dotcloud)
  Downloading argparse-1.2.1.tar.gz (69Kb): 69Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package argparse
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.orig' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.rej' found anywhere in distribution
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/_build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'env24'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'env25'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'env26'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'env27'
Downloading/unpacking requests==0.14.1 (from dotcloud)
  Downloading requests-0.14.1.tar.gz (523Kb): 523Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package requests
    warning: no files found matching 'tests/*.'
Downloading/unpacking colorama (from dotcloud)
  Downloading colorama-0.2.4.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package colorama
Installing collected packages: dotcloud, argparse, requests, colorama
  Running setup.py install for dotcloud
    changing mode of build/scripts-2.6/dotcloud from 644 to 755
    changing mode of /usr/local/bin/dotcloud to 755
  Found existing installation: argparse 1.2.1
    Uninstalling argparse:
      Successfully uninstalled argparse
  Running setup.py install for argparse
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.orig' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.rej' found anywhere in distribution
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/_build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'env24'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'env25'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'env26'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'env27'
  Found existing installation: requests 0.14.1
    Uninstalling requests:
      Successfully uninstalled requests
  Running setup.py install for requests
    warning: no files found matching 'tests/*.'
  Found existing installation: colorama 0.2.4
    Uninstalling colorama:
      Successfully uninstalled colorama
  Running setup.py install for colorama
Successfully installed dotcloud argparse requests colorama
Cleaning up...
```

When I run `dotcloud setup`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/dotcloud", line 16, in <module>
    cli = CLI(endpoint=url, debug=debug, username=username)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/dotcloud/ui/cli.py", line 42, in __init__
    user_agent=self._build_useragent_string(),
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/dotcloud/ui/cli.py", line 72, in     _build_useragent_string
    (langcode, encoding) = locale.getdefaultlocale()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/locale.py", line 459, in getdefaultlocale
    return _parse_localename(localename)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/locale.py", line 391, in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError, 'unknown locale: %s' % localename
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: What version of python are you using? It looks like 2.6, is that the stock version that came with your system or do you have a custom install?

Comment: @Ken Cochrane Yea it's the stock one. I do have python 3.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is either a locale problem, or a permission problem.

You might not have a default locale set, or it can't load the locale correctly when needed.

Instead of copying all the info over you should look at this question for your answer it might help.

[python locale strange error. what's going on here exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830394/python-locale-strange-error-whats-going-on-here-exactly)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the cli is accessing the locale._parse_localname method and is encountering a ValueError because it can't find a locale for the value UTF-8.

The link to this blog post provided below suggests that if you modify your ~/.bash_profile (or ~/.profile on some systems) and export the values, it will resolve the issue you're seeing.  If you do choose to modify your files, please be sure to back them up first (just in case!).

http://patrick.arminio.info/blog/2012/02/fix-valueerror-unknown-locale-utf8/