# Show QLatin1String concat of Unicode QString in a single string

Tags: c++, qt

I know the title is a bit confusing, even I don't know how to summarize it. Here is the issue.

I have two strings, one is an Extended ASCII (can be represented using `QLatin1String`) and a Unicode String (can be represented by a `QString`).

I am combining them using `QString::arg()` method as below.

```
QLatin1String latinStr = "Adiós";
QString unicodeStr = "some Uniocode හාහාහා %1";

QString newStr = unicodeStr.arg(latinStr);
```

Now this newStr has my concatenated string. If I print newStr, it prints "?" for the extended ASCII. If I convert the `newStr` to a `QLatin1String` using `QString::fromLatin1()`, the unicode part shows in a weird way.

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: That conversion to Latin1 breaks the Unicode string is clear. Don't see why newstr should be wrong though, assuming both Latin1str and UnicodeStr are correct. Are they both displayed correctly individually?

Comment: Yes, if I print them separately, they look fine. My concern is how to print the combined string.

Answer (score 0):

You may be having issues with your locale and/or with fonts. Make sure your font supports Unicode. Since this is OS-dependent, I will list the options on an OS basis.

### Windows

You absolutely will have Unicode support for QT, so it is likely a problem of the fonts available.

### Linux

Your distribution would have already configured the locale. You may have changed it or are using a bare-bones distribution such as Arch Linux, in which case you should check their wiki or search online.

### OS X

You will want to look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8161863/4147262

Comment: The issue cannot be with the font or locale, since those two strings are represented perfectly when they were used individually. My concern is, how to display them properly *after* combining them.