# How to make Git print date in a different locale?

Tags: git, locale

This is what I'm doing:

```
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8 git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ad '--date=format:%B %e, %Y'
```

I'm getting:

```
March 23, 2016
```

I'm expecting:

```
Март 23, 2016
```

What's wrong?

I'm checking my locale, seems to be OK:

```
$ LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8 locale
LANG="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

This is what I'm also doing:

```
$ export LANG=ru_RU
$ date +%c
пятница, 25 марта 2016 г. 16:49:56
$ git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ad '--date=format:%c'
Wed Mar 23 21:24:18 2016
```

WTF?

Comment: Works for me when I use `LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8 ` (the name of the various files varies somewhat on different OSes, so check your `/usr/share/locale`, assuming Unix-ish system).

Comment: @torek hm... I do have `/usr/share/locale/ru_RU.UTF-8` file (it's OSX), but still doesn't work for me

Comment: When you type "locale", is there any error? (as in http://blog.remibergsma.com/2012/07/10/setting-locales-correctly-on-mac-osx-terminal-application/)

Comment: @VonC seems to be working.. I've updated my question

Comment: Just in case, try `export LANGUAGE=ru_RU.UTF-8` (as in http://askubuntu.com/a/311796/5470)

Comment: @VonC no go :( any other ideas?

Comment: Check if there are any other environment variable or strange folders in the $PATH that might interfer. Also http://stackoverflow.com/a/8161863/6309. Also check if that locale is actually installed: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/23175

Comment: @VonC this one works fine: `LC_ALL=ru_RU date +'%c'`, but in combination with Git I'm still getting English text

Comment: Did you uncheck the "Set locale environment variables on startup" as in http://blog.remibergsma.com/2012/07/10/setting-locales-correctly-on-mac-osx-terminal-application/? (and close and relaunch a shell window)

Comment: @VonC yes, I did. no luck... see my update of the question

Comment: Is there an alias for git? (`alias git`) What which `git --version` returns? And `which git`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107381/discussion-between-bernie-noel-and-vonc).