# Change jupyter notebook warnings language

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

As my jupyter notebook gives warnings in French, is there an easy way to switch to English?

(I am on macOS 10.12.2, with jupyter 4.2.1, using *R kernel*)

Comment: What happens when you run `locale` on the OS X command line?

Comment: here is the output: ```LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=```

Comment: One thing you can try is to manually set your locale in your `~/.profile` file (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8161863/554531). I didn't see any explicit language/locale options in Jupyter, so there is a reasonable chance it is simply auto-detected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work, just by adding these two lines, as suggested in the *last* answer of this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165108/in-osx-lion-lang-is-not-set-to-utf8-how-fix/8161863#8161863)

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

credits to [Keith Hughitt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/554531/keith-hughitt)