# ddd 'Can't open display' on macos

Tags: macos, ddd-debugger

I'd like to debug a cython program (following [this](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/DebuggingTechniques) tutorial).
To do so, I need `ddd`.
So, I run the following command: `brew install ddd`
but when the command `ddd python3` leads to:

```
Error: Can't open display:
```

What can I do to have more information on what is the problem and identify where it is coming from ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use `ddd`, but it appears to need X11, i.e. an X Windows server. As Macs no longer come with an X11 server, you'd need to install XQuartz which you can obtain [here](https://www.xquartz.org).

Also, I would imagine you need:

```
brew install ddd
```

rather than:

```
brew uninstall ddd
```

Comment: It was a typo, I edited the question. I did install XQuartz, but nothing changed

Comment: no. I just checked with a simple `xclock -digital` and I again get 
`Error: Can't open display:`

Comment: Well, if `xclock` won't run, your X setup is incorrect. Have you rebooted since installing XQuartz? Have you set DISPLAY or not? Have you tried manually starting X11 from Finder->Applications before starting `xclock`?

Comment: After a reboot, xclock is now working. When trying to excecute the command `ddd python3`, I now have the following error:`ddd python3
Warning: locale not supported by Xlib, locale set to C
Error: Unresolved inheritance operation

Xt error (Unresolved inheritance operation).

Oops!  You have found a bug in DDD.

If you can reproduce this bug, please send a bug report
to <ddd@gnu.org>, giving a subject like

    DDD 3.3.12 (i386-apple-darwin17.3.0) gets Xt error`

Comment: I'm approaching the limits of my knowledge now. This may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/8161863/2836621

Comment: I tried what you just suggest. Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem. Thanks for your help. I will post the solution to this problem if I manage to find one :)